# SQL how to show players not currently in a team

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller

I am trying to show players in a drop down view which is not already added to the chosen team.

When I put a = sign in my SQL-question I get all the players added to the team, but when I change it to <> it instead shows all players not in the current team but all other teams.

My problem is that I can't make a SQL-question that shows all players (PID, PlayerID) you (UID, TeamUID, PlayerUID) have created that is not currently in the choosen team (TID, TeamID).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Player_tbl.* 
FROM PlayerTeam_tbl 
left JOIN Player_tbl ON Player_tbl.PID = PlayerTeam_tbl.PlayerID 
WHERE TeamID <> 14 AND UID = 2
```

**Player_tbl**

| PID | Fornamn | Number | Coach | UID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Stephen | 85 |  | 2 |
| 16 | Axel | 47 | nej | 2 |
| 17 | Kaspar | 32 | nej | 2 |
| 18 | Mats | 66 | nej | 2 |
| 19 | Oskar | 99 | nej | 2 |

**Team_tbl**

| TID | Division | Team | Strength | TemUID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | u20 | KFUM... | bankvarmare | 2 |
| 17 | u17 | Malmo | mangd | 2 |
| 20 | u14 | KFUM... | give and go | 2 |
| 21 | u17 | Frovi FC | Maximus | 2 |
| 23 | u14 | Rovani... | 100 | 2 |
| 24 | u20 | Matss... | programering | 3 |
| 25 | u14 | test | testar | 2 |
| 26 | u17 | kalle k... | iq | 2 |
| 27 | u20 | London | vet inte | 5 |

**PlayerTeam_tbl**

| PTID | PlayerID | TeamID | TeamUID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 15 | 15 | 2 |
| 11 | 15 | 17 | 2 |
| 16 | 15 | 23 | 2 |
| 60 | 18 | 17 | 2 |
| 63 | 17 | 17 | 2 |
| 75 | 19 | 14 | 2 |
| 77 | 16 | 14 | 2 |
| 80 | 17 | 14 | 2 |

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RF6D.png)

Comment: Can you tell which DBMS you are using? And provide the data as text (not as picture) with some desired output, based on some input data ?

Comment: You can't filter on the inner table after using an outer join. I think you want to reverse the tables though. Check for null on the player team side to find players unmatched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the result you want: **only player 15 and 18 should be shown as play 17 are in both team 14 and team 17)**

If your DB Engine support [NOT IN subquery](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), you can simply get ther result with NOT IN subquery.

Here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qdeF1ZQvDXALCDxBDQ8xjB/2):

```
SELECT Player_tbl.pid, fornamn,number,coach,uid
FROM Player_tbl
where pid NOT in (
    SELECT
        PlayerID
    FROM
        PlayerTeam_tbl
    WHERE
        TeamID = 14
)
```

| pid | fornamn | number | coach | uid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Stephen | 85 | null | 2 |
| 18 | Mats | 66 | nej | 2 |

If your DB engine dones't support NOT In sub query, you can put player_tbl in the left side of the join, and use [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator with [having clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to filter any player in team 14.

Here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qdeF1ZQvDXALCDxBDQ8xjB/1):

```
SELECT Player_tbl.pid, fornamn,number,coach,uid
FROM Player_tbl 
left JOIN PlayerTeam_tbl ON Player_tbl.PID = PlayerTeam_tbl.PlayerID 
WHERE UID = 2
GROUP BY Player_tbl.pid, fornamn,number,coach,uid
HAVING sum(case when TeamID= 14 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

| pid | fornamn | number | coach | uid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Stephen | 85 | null | 2 |
| 18 | Mats | 66 | nej | 2 |

Comment: Hi! Your soultion worked. However, now I just want the players that "you" have created (UID = 2) to appear. When I made a new player from a different account it also appears, 
which I don't want. I tried "where PID NOT in (SELECT * FROM PlayerTeam_tbl WHERE TeamID = 24 AND TeamUID <> 2)" but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database you're on, assuming it is MS SQL the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayerTbl 
WHERE PID NOT IN 
(SELECT PlayerID from PlayerTeam where TEAMUID = @teamid)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be a left-join.  HOWEVER, to clarify, if you rely on that, you would get everyone NOT on the team.  -- OR--  Do you mean you want a list of all players who are not on ANY team.  How could one person be associated with two active teams.

```
SELECT 
      P.* 
   FROM 
      PlayerTbl P
         LEFT JOIN PlayerTeam PT
            on P.PlayerID = PT.PlayerID
   WHERE
      PT.PID IS NULL
```

The point here with the WHERE clause is that the player is not on ANY team, regardless of your interest in team 1, 2, 14, 27, whatever.  If they are not on a team, they can be assigned to ANY team.